# Serve HTML with gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I have a golang app that needs a homepage. I'm struggling to get it to serve a simple html file. I'm able to do it locally like this:

```
router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views/")))
```

This works for me on Windows and Pop OS, however, when I deploy this to my ubuntu server on AWS, it says 404 not found.

Comment: Are you sure you deploy static files (./views directory) too and since you refer to it using relative path; also that binary running on AWS runs in ./views/.. working directory?

Comment: you can also use [os.Getwd](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getwd) to get current working directory and assign it to constant then reuse that across code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ubuntu use full adress like http.dir(/root/workpath/yourgofolder/projectfolder/